# MooTools / LinkedIn JS (jQuery?) conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, linkedin-api

I need to add a LinkedIn widget (so called [Company Insider Plugin](http://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/company-insider-plugin)) on a page which relies on Mootools, but it seems to be causing a confict in JSON encoder implementation.

The error happening is `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'encode'` happening in the following Mootools code when LinkedIn script is executed:

```
Native.implement([Hash, Array, String, Number], {
toJSON: function(){
    return JSON.encode(this);
}
});
```

I tried "resetting" the conflicting entity as [advised](http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/conflict-mootools-js-framework) but with no effect (but that's probably an advice for a different kind of conflict).

What else can I do? There is no critical Mootools code after the LinkedIn one on the page so if I could 'disable' Mootools in a way for that script to work that'd be still fine.

Comment: Are you testing in an older version of IE?

Comment: this looks like a really old version of MooTools - Hash is now defunct.

Comment: this plugin causes various exceptions in FF19 w/o a framework at all..

Comment: Didn't test in IE yet, but it happens for FF in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved via iframing the Linked snippet I needed.

Doesn't answer the question but solves the problem.